# Build iOS app directly from iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone-app, ipad-app

I am trying to build an app which contains a simple webview. I solved that for android. I created the app directly from Android using this coding IDE App (AIDE: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui).

Is there such a FREE app for iPhone? I don't have a Mac to run XCode on it but I have an iPhone. The app should run on iPhones (and maybe on iPads too).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Wouldn't the screen be too small to achieve anything meaningful? It might be nice to ask this, just out of curiosity, but would you really expect to use it regularly? Btw, if it must be free, elapse use the [tag:gratis] tag; otherwise, please state a budget

Comment: @Mawg I want to build only one app with a WebView, embedding a website. I think it makes no sense to buy an Apple computer just for that. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: what programming language would you use?

Comment: Would it make sense to buy a used iPad?